BLe data not receiving in query method in my app but works in bluetooth terminal app
in BLE unable to read the receiving response from the device .while i send request to ble device the command sends but the response is not logging in my app but if i connect the same device to the bluetooth trminal app and send request in my app the response is received by the bluetooth terminal app`
package com.example.terminal;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.media.session.MediaSession;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import kotlin.Suppress;

public class terminalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = terminalActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt;

    private ListView servicesListView;
    private ListView characteristicsListView;
    private EditText messageEditText;
    private Button sendButton;
    private Button readButton;
    private ListView logsListView;
    private TextView logsTitle;

    private List<BluetoothGattService> servicesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> servicesAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> characteristicsAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> logsAdapter;
    private List<String> logsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic selectedReadCharacteristic;
    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic selectedWriteCharacteristic;

    private boolean connected = false;
    private final Handler mainLooper = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    private final ArrayDeque<byte[]> lastRead = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private final ArrayDeque<MediaSession.QueueItem> queue1 = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private final ArrayDeque<MediaSession.QueueItem> queue2 = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public static void setBluetoothGatt(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
        bluetoothGatt = gatt;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_terminal);

        servicesListView = findViewById(R.id.servicesListView);
        characteristicsListView = findViewById(R.id.characteristicsListView);
        messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        readButton = findViewById(R.id.readButton);
        logsListView = findViewById(R.id.logsListView);
        logsTitle = findViewById(R.id.logsTitle);

        servicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        characteristicsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        logsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, logsList);

        servicesListView.setAdapter(servicesAdapter);
        characteristicsListView.setAdapter(characteristicsAdapter);
        logsListView.setAdapter(logsAdapter);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String message = messageEditText.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        });

        readButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (selectedReadCharacteristic != null) {
                boolean success = bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(selectedReadCharacteristic);
                if (success) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Reading characteristic: " + selectedReadCharacteristic.getUuid());
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read characteristic: " + selectedReadCharacteristic.getUuid());
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No read characteristic selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        servicesListView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
            String selectedItem = servicesAdapter.getItem(position);
            if (selectedItem != null) {
                UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(selectedItem);
                for (BluetoothGattService service : servicesList) {
                    if (service.getUuid().equals(uuid)) {
                        showCharacteristics(service);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        characteristicsListView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
            String selectedItem = characteristicsAdapter.getItem(position);
            if (selectedItem != null) {
                UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(selectedItem);
                for (BluetoothGattService service : servicesList) {
                    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : service.getCharacteristics()) {
                        if (characteristic.getUuid().equals(uuid)) {
                            toggleCharacteristicSelection(characteristic);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        discoverServices();
    }

    private void discoverServices() {
        if (bluetoothGatt != null) {
            servicesList = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
            List<String> serviceNames = new ArrayList<>();
            for (BluetoothGattService service : servicesList) {
                serviceNames.add(service.getUuid().toString());
            }
            servicesAdapter.clear();
            servicesAdapter.addAll(serviceNames);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "BluetoothGatt is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void showCharacteristics(BluetoothGattService service) {
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
        List<String> characteristicNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics) {
            characteristicNames.add(characteristic.getUuid().toString());
        }
        characteristicsAdapter.clear();
        characteristicsAdapter.addAll(characteristicNames);
    }

    private void toggleCharacteristicSelection(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) != 0) {
            selectedReadCharacteristic = characteristic;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected read characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) != 0 ||
                (characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE) != 0) {
            selectedWriteCharacteristic = characteristic;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected write characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Enable notifications if the characteristic supports them
        if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) != 0) {
            bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
            if (descriptor != null) {
                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                boolean success = bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                if (!success) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to write descriptor for notifications: " + characteristic.getUuid());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Notification enabled for characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (selectedWriteCharacteristic != null) {
            byte[] value = hexStringToByteArray(message);
            value = appendChecksum(value);
            selectedWriteCharacteristic.setValue(value);
            boolean success = bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(selectedWriteCharacteristic);
            if (success) {
                String hexString = byteArrayToHexString(value);
                Log.d(TAG, "Message sent: " + hexString);
                addLog("Sent: " + hexString);

                // Log state "waiting for reply" and trigger read after sending message
                Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for reply...");
                addLog("State: Waiting for reply...");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send message: " + message);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No write characteristic selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private byte[] appendChecksum(byte[] data) {
        int crc = CRC16.crc16(data);
        byte[] result = new byte[data.length + 2];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, result, 0, data.length);
        result[result.length - 2] = (byte) ((crc >> 8) & 0xFF);
        result[result.length - 1] = (byte) (crc & 0xFF);
        return result;
    }

    private byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

    private String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void addLog(String log) {
        logsList.add(log);
        logsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                gatt.discoverServices();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                connected = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Services discovered: " + gatt.getServices().size());
                discoverServices();
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            if (connected) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (lastRead.isEmpty()) {
                        mainLooper.post(() -> {
                            synchronized (lastRead) {
                                while (!lastRead.isEmpty()) {
                                    byte[] data = lastRead.poll();
                                    addLog("Read: " + byteArrayToHexString(data));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    lastRead.add(characteristic.getValue());
                }
            }
        }

        @Deprecated

        public void onCharacteristicChanged(
                BluetoothGatt gatt,
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                byte[] value
        ) {
            String newValueHex = byteArrayToHexString(value);
            Log.i("BluetoothGattCallback", "Characteristic " + characteristic.getUuid() + " changed | value: " + newValueHex);
            if (connected) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (lastRead.isEmpty()) {
                        mainLooper.post(() -> {
                            synchronized (lastRead) {
                                while (!lastRead.isEmpty()) {
                                    byte[] data = lastRead.poll();
                                    addLog("Read: " + byteArrayToHexString(data));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    lastRead.add(value);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            if (descriptor.getCharacteristic() == selectedReadCharacteristic) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Descriptor write finished, status=" + status);
                if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Write descriptor failed");
                } else {
                    onSerialConnect();
                    connected = true;
                    Log.d(TAG, "connected");
                }
            }
        }

        private void onSerialConnect() {
            runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(terminalActivity.this, "Connected to device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
        }
    };



private static class CRC16 {
        public static int crc16(byte[] bytes) {
            int crc = 0xFFFF;
            for (byte b : bytes) {
                crc = ((crc >>> 8) | (crc << 8)) & 0xffff;
                crc ^= (b & 0xff);
                crc ^= ((crc & 0xff) >> 4);
                crc ^= (crc << 12) & 0xffff;
                crc ^= ((crc & 0xFF) << 5) & 0xffff;
            }
            return crc & 0xffff;
        }
    }

}



// Commenting out the characteristic read callback
//        @Override
//        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
//            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
//            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
//                byte[] charValue = characteristic.getValue();
//                if (charValue != null && charValue.length > 0) {
//                    String hexString = byteArrayToHexString(charValue);
//                    Log.i(TAG, "Characteristic Value: " + hexString);
//                } else {
//                    Log.e(TAG, "Empty characteristic value");
//                }
//            } else {
//                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid() + ", status: " + status);
//            }
//        }

// Commenting out the characteristic changed callback
//        @Override
//        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
//            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
//
//            byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
//            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
//                String hexString = byteArrayToHexString(data);
//                Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic changed: " + hexString);
//                addLog("Received: " + hexString);
//
//                // Process the received data here
//                // Example: Unpack the frame and convert hex string to integer
//                int frameData = processFrame(hexString);
//                Log.d(TAG, "Processed frame data: " + frameData);
//
//                // Update UI or perform other operations with the processed data
//            } else {
//                Log.e(TAG, "Empty characteristic value");
//            }
//        }
//        private int processFrame(String hexString) {
//            // Assuming the frame structure is: <header(2 bytes)><data(2 bytes)><crc(2 bytes)>
//            // You may need to modify this based on your actual frame structure
//
//            int header = Integer.parseInt(hexString.substring(0, 4), 16);
//            int data = Integer.parseInt(hexString.substring(4, 8), 16);
//            int crc = Integer.parseInt(hexString.substring(8), 16);
//
//            // Perform any necessary checks or validation on the header, data, and crc
//
//            // Return the data portion of the frame
//            return data;
//        }

// Commenting out the descriptor read callback
//        @Override
//        public void onDescriptorRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
//            super.onDescriptorRead(gatt, descriptor, status);
//            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
//                Log.d(TAG, "Descriptor read: " + descriptor.getUuid());
//            } else {
//                Log.w(TAG, "Descriptor read failed, status: " + status);
//            }
//        }
//
//        @Override
//        public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
//            super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
//            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
//                Log.d(TAG, "Descriptor write successful: " + descriptor.getUuid());
//            } else {
//                Log.w(TAG, "Descriptor write failed, status: " + status);
//            }
//        }
//    };



i need to complete the read process and display the response .

I recommend reading (https://bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-part-1/) and (https://bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-part-2/ ) especially the part relating to BluetoothGattServerCallback.onCharacteristicWriteRequest
